# Passing data from a surfaceView to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bundle, surfaceview

An explanation of the code below: The task i'm trying to accomplish is to send a boolean from my surfaceview activity (surfaceActivity) to my main activity (mainActivity). Below are 4 parts of my code, the initializing of mainActivity, the initializing of surfaceActivity, how I send the boolean, and how I receive the boolean. Apparently the code i'm using to send/receive information is what most people have been having success with across the internet, it's just that my case is a bit different considering I have two activities, but surfaceActivity is set through mainActivity, thus not really being independent.

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(new surfaceActivity(this));

           private Bundle bundle;
      }
 }
```

Which then leads to my surfaceView

```
public class surfaceActivity extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
     private MainThread thread;
     private Context context;

     public surfaceActivity(Context context) {
     super(context);
     getHolder().addCallback(this);
     thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

     this.context = context;

     setFocusable(true);
     }
```

Then when a touch on the screen is registered:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);             
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("boo",true);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActionMode((Callback) i);
```

And then in a constantly repeating loop back on the MainActivity class:

```
if (bundle != null)
{
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Boolean stuff = bundle.getBoolean("boo"); 
}
```

Also, most people have been using startActivity(i);  but eclipse corrects it to startActionMode((Callback) i);

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity is an Activity and SurfaceActivity (even though the name says Activity) is just a View that has been added as the content view for the MainActivity.
MainActivity can declare a reference to the SurfaceActivity as an Instance variable, and then it can read the values from the SurfaceActivity.

Intent based mechanism is generally used to pass values between Activities, in your case, you don't have 2 Activities. You have one Activity and one View.

Comment: how would a go about sending info from my view to its parent activity?

Comment: There are multiple ways of going about the same. You can create the SurfaceActivity as an inner class of the MainActivity. Inner class will have access to all instance variables and methods of the outer class. Hence the SurfaceActivity can directly set variables in the MainActivity.

Comment: You are passing a reference of MainActivity to the SurfaceActivity in the constructor. You can cast the Context variable to MainActivity and set values using mutator methods in the MainActivity.

Comment: The most flexible way to the same would however be to use the Listener mechanism in Java.

Comment: can you explain further on your second comment?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a method in the `MainActivity` from the `SurfaceView` (in the OP example, `SurfaceActivity`), you could do this:

The `MainActivity` set-up:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new surfaceActivity(this));
        private Bundle bundle;
    }

    // Method to be called from the SurfaceView
    public void callMe(String valuePassed) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","MainActivity was passed ["+ valuePassed +"]");
    }
}
```

The `SurfaceView` set-up:

```
public class SurfaceActivity extends SurfaceView 
                             implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MainThread thread;
    private Context context;

    public SurfaceActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        this.context = context;

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    // This is where and how you make the call to MainActivity.
    // You cast the context as the MainActivity and call the method.
    private void passToMainActivity(String valToPass) {
        ((MainActivity) context).callMe(valToPass);
    }
}
```